# Private key access error

Tags: wcf, x509certificate

Im trying to make a WCF webservice with security based on certificates. 
On the server i have a certificate with a private key and on the client a certificate with a public key. 
When i try to run the client i get an error saying 'The process must have access rights for the private key'
No my question is, is this a server error or is it cause the client must have a certificate with the private key.

Thanks

Comment: I think that it is a server error, caused by the account that your WCF service is running under not having privileges to access the private key in the certificate store. Clients should never have access to the private key. See here for details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702621.aspx

Comment: If you're trying to sign the communication (which is the default behavior), you need to have a client certificate (so the client owns the private key).

Comment: #DeanOC, Cool will try that

Comment: #zimdanen, The server cert is the one with the private key and the client is the one with the public key. Is the what you mean?

Comment: @hippie - FYI, to reply to a comment so that commenter gets notified, you need to put a @ in front of name not #. (exception is the OP who gets notified when any comment is posted IIRC). Cheers.

Comment: Did you have any luck solving your problem?

Comment: @DeanOc - Thanks for the @ info. No i didnt solve the problem. What we done is to run it behind https instead.
Next ill try to create a SelfContaind service instead of running it througt the IIS